# d3.js v4 dragging zoomed elements jumping mouse

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi Stackoverflow Community!

I have following problem: 
I created a d3 force-directed graph with div as nodes and included a d3-zoom behavior. 
When I zoomed out or zoomed in a lot then the dragging of nodes became either too fast(when zoomed in) or too slow(when zoomed out). 
I fixed that by applying d3.mouse(d3.select(".links").node()) so that the mouse coordinates will be taken from inside the zoomed area.

But since i did that i notice that when dragging a node this node jumps. It centers on the mousepointer instead just following the mouse.

After some research I tried fixing this by specifying a subject like so:

```
d3.drag().subject(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: parseInt(t.style("left"),10), y: parseInt(t.style("top"),10)};
    })
```

But it didn't have any influence and i'm out of ideas now. I'm happy if someone could help me here..

Following fiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jxkgfdcm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It jumps to the centre of the node because in  drag you are doing:

```
function dragged(d) {
  var coordinates = [0, 0];
  coordinates = d3.mouse(d3.select(".links").node()); //this will give the link end location..so it will jump to the centre of the node
  var x = coordinates[0];
  var y = coordinates[1];

  d.fx = x;
  d.fy = y;


  d.fixed = true;
}
```

it should have been:

```
function dragged(d) {

  d.fx += d3.event.dx;//give delta increment to current position
  d.fy += d3.event.dy//give delta increment to current position

  d.fixed = true;
}
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/njxe1dm3/)

Comment: Hi Cyril, yes this doesn't have the problem with the jumping mouse but it does return me the problem with the slow following drag. When u zoom out the graph and then drag a node you will see what i mean

Comment: check this...i keep a global variable to store scale and use that to calculate the drag https://jsfiddle.net/rn9w88m6/